# incompatible types of assignment of 'const char [2] to char [1]'

Tags: c++

I wrote this code (I just started coding btw), and there's an error in 13:17:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [2]' to 'char [1]'

This error can also be found in 27:25.

It's not a problem of how I can fix it, but rather of explaining why using `if(opinion="y")` doesn't work because it's a char. I've tried using `cin.getline()` without any result (I haven't learned that yet (I did use `#incude <string>` even though string is included in the `std` library)

Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int mycarrots=10;        //Initiates number of carrots that I have (mycarrots)
    int yourcarrots=0;      //Inititate the numbe of carrots the user has
    int wantcarrots=0;      //initiates the number of carrots user wants
    int wantcarrots2=0;     //initiates how many more carrots user wants apart from the ones that I can give him
    char opinion1[1], opinion2[1];          //initiates opinion whether user want carrots. Opionion2 Initiates opinion whether user has enough money to buy more carrots
    int ymoney=0;           //initiates how much money the user has
    cout<<"I have some carrots I want to give away, would you like some? (y/n)"<<endl;          //initiates convo, ask user whether he wants carrts
    cin>>opinion1;                                                                              //input of opinion (y/n)
    if (opinion1="n"){                                                                       //if the opinion is no, execute "Have a good day"
        cout<<"Have a good day!"<<endl;
        }
    else {                                                                                      //otherwise, resume convo
        cout<<"How many do you want?"<<endl;
        cin>>wantcarrots;
        if (wantcarrots>mycarrots){
            cout<<"I don't have that many carrots, you'll have to get some from the store."<<endl;
            cout<<"They're $1.5 each, so you'll have to pay "<<(wantcarrots-mycarrots)*1.5<<" dollars";
            cout<<"do you have enough money for that? (y/n)"<<endl;
            cin.getline(opinion2,1);
            wantcarrots2=wantcarrots-mycarrots;
            if (opinion2="y"){
                      cout<<"I can give you "<<mycarrots<<" carrots, but you'll have to get the other"<<mycarrots-wantcarrots<<" from the store."<<endl;
                     cout<<"Now off you go to the store then.";
                     }
            else {
                     cout<<"how much money do you have?"<<endl;
                     cin>>ymoney;
                     if (ymoney>=(wantcarrots2*1.5)){
                        cout<<"Off you go to the store."<<endl;
                        }
                     else if (ymoney<(wantcarrots2*1.5)){
                        cout<<"You'll have to settle for "<<ymoney/1.5<<" carrots."<<endl;
                        }       
                    }}
            else{
                cout<<"fatal errors. i am not prgrammed to do this"<<endl;}
            }
       else {
            cout<<"Here are your "<<wantcarrots<<" carrots"<<endl;
            cout<<"now you have "<<yourcarrots<<" carrots"<<endl;}
return 0;
            }
```

Comment: First of all, `opinion2="y"` is an assignment, not a comparison. Secondly, I highly recommend using std::string instead of character pointers.

Comment: None of `opinion1` and `"y"` is `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(opinion="y")` won't work because `opinion` is not declared and `if(opinion1="y")` won't work because you cannot assign to arrays.

To check if what iss read is `y`, try `if(*opinion1 == 'y')`.

Points are

- Do compare, not assignment.
- Dereference the pointer converted from array before compareing. You can also use `opinion1[0]`.
- Use character literal instead of string literal.

**UPDATE:** As @SamVarshavchik suggests, this code will cause out-of-bounds access.

If you don't change type of `opinion1`, use `cin.get(*option1);` instead of `cin>>opinion1;`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem with this code that's pointed out in other answers, I'll also point out that if the input is anything other than an empty string, this results in memory corruption and undefined behavior.

```
char opinion1[1]
```

A one character array only accomodates an empty string...

```
cin>>opinion1;
```

... and as soon as one character is entered here, this will overflow the array buffer, corrupt the stack, and result in undefined behavior.